# Why did we cancel (secα)^2 although it could equal to zero ???

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**For example**:

If $x=(\sec \alpha)^2-1$, $y=\tan\alpha$ , $\alpha =(-\frac{3\pi}{4})$

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

---

**Solution**:

$X=(\sec\alpha)^2-1 .....$ 
Derivating both sides by $\alpha$,

$$\frac{dy}{d\alpha}=2(\sec\alpha)^2.\tan\alpha$$
$Y=\tan\alpha$ 
Derivate both sides by $\alpha$:
$$\frac{dy}{d\alpha}=(\sec\alpha)^2$$
Using chain rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\alpha}\cdot \frac{d\alpha}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(\sec\alpha)^2/2(\sec\alpha)^2\cdot \tan\alpha$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\tan\alpha$$
At $\alpha=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$, we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=1/2$.

> Why did we cancel $(\sec \alpha)^2$ although it could equal to zero ?

Comment: How could $(\sec\alpha)^2$ be equal to zero??? What value of $\alpha$ do you think makes $\sec\alpha=0$? And what is $\cos\alpha$?

Comment: In the first step x could equal be 1-1=0

Comment: That's not readable. Try MathJax, please, and logic.

Comment: Please try to use MathJaX in your equations from the next time. Else no one will feel interested to read it. This time, I have edited it.

Comment: Ok bro srry about that i didnt know

Comment: I am sure I am in a minority but when I was starting out in advanced mathematics in 1994 the word derivate was never a word. Do you mean differentiate?

Comment: @kevin yes bro that what i mean

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for $\sec\alpha$ to be equal to $0$.

Comment: In the first step X could be equal to 1-1=0

Comment: @medoadel24 So what? You didn't cancel $x$, you cancelled out $\sec\alpha$...

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible because if $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}=0$ then $1=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Cos 0=1 so how is that

Comment: @medoadel24 $\frac{1}{\cos^20}=\frac{1}{1^2}=1,$ but you wish that $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}=0$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha} = 0$ implies $1=0$... how exactly?

Comment: @5xum If $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}=0$ then $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}\cdot\cos^2\alpha=0\cdot\cos^2\alpha$ or $1=0$.

Comment: Yes oh thanks ....but in many problems i saw cancelling variables could be equal to zero

Comment: @medoadel24 Try to think about the problem, which you need to solve. If you'll think about things that have no any relation with your problem then you don't solve your problem. I hope my words will help.

Comment: Ok but thats my problem

Comment: @medoadel24 Because you got the answer on your question (see please my post) and we have no contradictions in math. It's all. You can take another problem and  solve it. Do it please!

Comment: @michael where is your post??? Any link??

Comment: @medoadel24 See above: "it's impossible...."

Comment: Yes i understood that sec couldnt be equal to zero but iam saying that in other problems i am seeing cancelling variables could be equal to zero (in algebra and calculus)